# chmod unable to change permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pem

I'm facing an annoying problem. It's been pretty frustrating. I am using a computer at my school to work on the Coursera Startup class. I am trying to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance. I downloaded the key pair. I check permissions.

```
mac5-library:startup roh21$ ls -l
total 6
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 roh21  108  1692 Jun 22 16:45 startup-class-key.pem
```

So, it's not secure. So I need to change the permissions. I try:

```
mac5-library:startup roh21$ chmod 400 startup-class-key.pem
mac5-library:startup roh21$ ls -l
total 6
-r--r--r--@ 1 roh21  108  1692 Jun 22 16:45 startup-class-key.pem
```

Still has read permissions to everyone. Just to demonstrate what happens I do this:

```
mac5-library:startup roh21$ chmod 600 startup-class-key.pem
mac5-library:startup roh21$ ls -l
total 6
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 roh21  108  1692 Jun 22 16:45 startup-class-key.pem
```

Is it impossible to change permissions to the user without root permission? I'd be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Is the file on an external disk, or on the Amazon server, or something like that?

Comment: Gordon, No to both.

 What did help was, I copied the file to my ~/.ssh folder and then changed the permissions with `chmod`. That did it. I have no idea why though. If you can explain that, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if the file was on some sort of volume that didn't fully support permissions. If it wasn't an external volume, maybe a disk image, some other sort of remote volume, something other than Mac OS Extended format,... something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I copied the file to my `~/.ssh` folder and then changed the permissions with `chmod`. That did it.

Just to provide more information, the permissions for the ssh folder,

```
drwx------    8 roh21  108      272 Jun 26 17:26 .ssh
```

And the permissions to the folder I used initially

```
drwxrwxrwx    2 roh21  108     2048 Jun 23 06:32 startup
```

I curious as to why I could not change the permissions to the `startup` folder even after multiple attempts with the `chmod -R` option.

Also, note that I was using Mac OS X in my school's library.

Answer (score 35):

Probably not related to initial questions problem, but can be useful. (especially to Unix novices like myself)

*Chmod* will not work if you are not an owner of resources.

You should run *chown* first:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
```

and then

```
$ sudo chmod -R +rwX .
```

First command will change owner of everything in current folder  to be logged in user, and second give them read write execute permissions. 
Just for example, you, probably, should not change ownership and permissions so boldly.

Comment: Thank you so much! Way better solution than anyone else's

Comment: This is awesome. Running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) .` in the project directory fixed the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: It is great. Solved my whole sudo issue

Comment: what worked for me was small letter x
`$ sudo chmod -R +rwx .`

Answer (score 15):

Please note you may get "Operation not permitted" at your Terminal when you want to run "chflags nouchg". So, first you should give your Terminal "Full Disk Access" here:

System Settings --> Privacy & Security --> Full Disk Access --> check the Terminal

then close and re-open your Terminal.

Now, run "chflags nouchg PathToYourFolder"

Finally:

chmod 400 YourFile

Done!

Comment: I didn't need to run `chflags`, it worked by just setting the Full Disk Access option. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[Looks like you've discovered that the Macintosh doesn't strictly agree with the UNIX permission bits](http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/unix-permissions-on-os-x.html).

Ultimately, there are ACL bits that MacOS sets and that the Macintosh Finder obeys.

To solve your problem quickly, in your Terminal command line, type in "`open .`" (or the path to your "`startup`" folder) and that will open up the folder in your Macintosh Finder.

Then do a "Get Info" on the file:
[image: Sharing & Permissions]

You can change your permissions here.

Comment: Michael, that you for the detailed response. But that did not help - it does not give me the option to change Permissions in Get Info. All I see there is http://i.imgur.com/8mGsHeO.png


EDIT: What did help was, I copied the file to my ~/.ssh folder and then changed the permissions with `chmod`. That did it. I have no idea why though. If you can explain that in your post, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: It looks like the `uchg` extended flag is set, which prevents you from changing anything about the file. You can remove it from the command line with `chflags nouchg <file>`

Answer (score 5):

See that '@' next to the mode flags? That means that there's extended metadata associated with the file. Use `ls -l@` to see it. The `xattr` command will let you view and modify them. It's possible that there's something there that prevents you from modifying the file.

There may also be additional file flags. Use `ls -lO` (capital-O) to view those. Odds are that one of those flags is the "uchg" flag which means your file is immutable. You can remove that with `chflags nouchg <filename>` as أحمد طه suggested.

Finally, there might be an ACL attached to the file. Use `ls -le` to see that.

In general, if you really want to know all the metadata associated with a file on a Mac, the command is `ls -leO@`.

Answer (score 2):

Hello And it will work

```
chflags nouchg /path/folder/
```