# chmod just does nothing on my Mac?

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod

I am the owner, as shown by `ls -alts`, but for whatever reason, I can't change the permissions of the files like I want.  I want to make the file read only:

```
chmod 400 <file-name>
```

however, the `ls -al` still shows `-rwxrwxrwx`.

The file is on an external drive.  I know that sometimes this causes issues when users want to read and write.  However, in this case, I'd like to make the access to my files *more restrictive* not less restrictive.

I checked out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255340/chmod-unable-to-change-permissions) but I don't see an option to make the permissions more restrictive.

thanks.

Comment: this question may be similar to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255340/chmod-unable-to-change-permissions

Comment: What's the full path to the file and what version of OS X are you using here?

Comment: The file is on an external drive, i.e. under `Volume` on a Mac.  Version of OS is Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0.

Comment: What format is the external volume? Some formats (e.g. FAT) don't support permissions, and even Mac OS Extended gets special permissions behavior (by default) on external disks.

Comment: It is FAT 32 format.

Comment: So, is there no possible way to edit my files on an external drive in FAT 32 format?  I feel like there must be a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the permissions on the file because it's on a FAT32 volume, and that volume format does not support storing file permissions (see, for example, [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118199/how-do-i-change-file-permissions-on-a-fat32-drive)). But if all you want to to is make the file read-only, you can get that effect by locking it (and the lock attribute *is* supported on FAT32). You can either use the Finder's Get Info window (check the "Locked" box), or use the command `chflags uchg <file-name>`.