# Change file permission of com.apple.screensharing.plist file on mac

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod, screensharing

I'm trying to change the file permission of a file.

I have tried chmod 777 on the file and nothing seems to work.

I even tried manually navigating to it and unocking and changing the permissions via the answers here ([chmod unable to change permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255340/chmod-unable-to-change-permissions)), I am at a loss for how to change the file permission so I can edit this file to allow screen sharing on a different port...

[image]

For anyone else that has a mac I'm trying to follow the instructions here, https://superuser.com/questions/148095/how-to-change-the-default-screen-sharing-vnc-port-number-on-mac-os-x

```
sudo vim /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

This is the path to the file, but I can't edit it no matter what I do.  **Even as super user!**

Comment: To the -1 vote person, please explain why the downvote? I believe I demonstrated attempts at this myself and was legitimately not sure of the answer (at least until recently).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this, there is a protection on the system file csrutil, you need to disable this by booting up into recovery mode and open the terminal program and run the command `csrutil disable`.

Make sure to reenable after making the change in recovery mode again!

Comment: I went to recovery mod, and see my System Integrity Protection status is `disabled`.