# Privileges PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Recently I’ve worked on a project with symphony. I have create a database, but was’ent found by Symphony. But without attention I have delete all privileges, include root… So all my databases are delete and I can’t create a new because I don’t have any privileges…

I have tried to change the file config.inc.php but without success. Beacause i can't don't have privileges too... I have tried to fix it with chmod but :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrgIf.png)

chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/philippe/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php: Operation not permitted

Could you tell me how can I fix it please ?

Best regards,

Philippe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chmod unable to change permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255340/chmod-unable-to-change-permissions)

Comment: You may also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges as this has to do with database permissions, not file permissions.